# same function from two ns clashes in repl

Tags: clojure

In my repl I have loaded ns from one file that has a function `parse`. So `(use 'demo.one)` works fine when typed in the repl.

Now I have another ns which has a function with the same name. When I type this `(use 'demo.two), it gives me an error.

How do I prevent the function name clashes in both the ns ? In the above I would like to use the function from the second ns only.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid clashes by `require`ing the namespace, and then fully qualifying your function call.

e.g.

```
(require 'demo.two)
(demo.two/parse "foo")
```

Answer (score 2):

There’s also a way to alias namespaces when you `require` them,

You can use `:as` with `:require`

```
(ns your.namespace
(:require [demo.one :as one])
(:require [demo.two :as two]))

(one/parse "foo") ; use the namespace demo.one parse function
(two/parse "foo") ; use the namespace demo.two parse function
```